# TortoiseHG clone not working and Verify action give warning

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am trying to clone a project from remote server and I am getting `about:data/.hgignore@91e50004122 no mathc found! [Code - 255]` error.

While verifying the repository, getting following warning.

```
% hg verify --verbose
repository uses revlog format 1
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 .hgignore@0: 91e5004a1522 in manifests not found
386 files, 22 changesets, 492 total revisions
1 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 0)
```

I also tried to use "Recover" option, but still it is not working.
"Recover" option gives the following messsage.

```
% hg recover --verbose
no interrupted transaction available
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue and clone the project.

Comment: You can try `hg verify` and see what it tell you.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned in my question hg verify gives the following warning.
% hg verify --verbose
repository uses revlog format 1
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 .hgignore@0: 91e5004a1522 in manifests not found
386 files, 22 changesets, 492 total revisions
1 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 0)

Comment: Have you read https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption ?

Comment: @DaveInCaz, Thanks for the link. I followed the steps. But still could not fix this issue. I noticed one issue. In the change set 0, I am not able to open .hgignore file . I get "File or diffs not displayed: data/.hgignore.i@91e5004a1522: no match found". So looks like .hginore file is missed even in changeset 0. The "4.3. Reconstructing missing revlogs" section in your link shows the option to fix the corrupt repository from changeset 1. But in my case, change set 0 itself has an issue. so not sure how to fix this. Please let me know if you have any suggestion on this.